# TextArea vs JTextArea Java

Tags: java, textarea

So I was messing around with JTextAreas for a text adventure game and using some code snippets that I found online. Some of these snippets would not work no matter what I tried, I then realize that Some of the snippets where from TextArea and not JTextArea. So what is the difference between the two? I found some out with a google search that the JTextArea class has to be embedded in a JScrollPane, but what does that mean?

Code that I'm using:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Text extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
     protected JTextField textField;
     protected JTextArea textArea;
     private final static String newline = "\n";

public Text() {
    super(new GridBagLayout());

    textField = new JTextField(75);
    textField.addActionListener(this);

    textArea = new JTextArea(5,75);
    textArea.setEditable(false);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);

    //Add Components to this panel.
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    add(textField, c);

    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.weightx = 1.0;
    c.weighty = 1.0;
    add(scrollPane, c);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    String text = textField.getText();
    textArea.append(text + newline);
    textField.selectAll();

    //Make sure the new text is visible, even if there
    //was a selection in the text area.
    textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
}

/**
 * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
 * this method should be invoked from the
 * event dispatch thread.
 */
private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Text adventure");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Add contents to the window.
    frame.add(new Text());

    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Schedule a job for the event dispatch thread:
    //creating and showing this application's GUI.
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TextArea was part of Java 1.0 it links to / uses the native OS TextArea component (modern OSes have built in GUI toolkits like this) but is problematic, like many other things in java.awt, in terms of cross platform compatibility.

JTextArea is part of (javax.) Swing. This project was developed after the significant issues with the peer components like TextArea, to provide a 100% java GUI solution that would be 100% cross platform (it's not completely 100%, but it's as good as you can get)

The other difference is that the old awt components were all thread-safe, whereas swing components are not. Swing components should only be modified by the UI thread. Use google for more information on this.

JTextArea will work fine outside of a JScrollPane, but often you want to use it within a JScrollPane so that its content can extend beyond the bounds of its layout.

These days, Swing and JavaFX are recommended over the GUI components contained in java.awt

Answer (score 3):

`javax.swing.JTextArea` is an old [Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/start/) component, while `java.awt.TextArea` is an even **older** [AWT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/package-summary.html) component (AWT stands for "Abstract Windows Toolkit" - some history [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Window_Toolkit)).

When you're using a `JScrollPane` or most Swing components, you're likely going to embed other Swing components.